# How to Inject constructor to abstract class with Dagger2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have an abstract ViewModel

```
abstract class AbstractViewModel(
    protected val dataStore: dataStore,
    protected val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
): ViewModel() {
   abstract fun doSomething()
}
```

that is inherited by many ViewModels

```
class InheritedViewModel1 @Inject constructor(
    dataStore: DataStore,
    schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : AbstractViewModel(packageDataStore, schedulerProvider) {

    override fun doSomething() {}
}

class InheritedViewModel2 @Inject constructor(
    dataStore: DataStore,
    schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : AbstractViewModel(packageDataStore, schedulerProvider) {

    override fun doSomething() {}
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, what bothers me is that I have many many ViewModels inheriting from the abstract class, thus, for each ViewModel I have to tell dagger to provide it like

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(InheritedViewModel1::class)
abstract fun InheritedViewModel1(inheritedViewModel1: InheritedViewModel1): ViewModel

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(InheritedViewModel2::class)
abstract fun InheritedViewModel2(inheritedViewModel2: InheritedViewModel2): ViewModel
```

I am wondering is there any way to move the @Inject annotation to the abstract class and thus only bind it to the abstract class. Something like

```
abstract class AbstractViewModel @Inject constuctor(
    protected val dataStore: dataStore,
    protected val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
): ViewModel() {
   abstract fun doSomething()
}

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(AbstractViewModel::class)
abstract fun AbstractViewModel(abstractViewModel: AbstractViewModel): ViewModel
```

And then remove all the injections from the inherited classes. Is this possible or is it just nonsense? If so, how should I instantiate the inherited classes?

Comment: `Is this possible?` Well, no. There are some possible work arounds but none of them will free you from having to declare them in the view model factory. If you can migrate to Hilt, that's also one thing that will remove the need to do this.